# How to EasyMock a call to a method that returns a wildcarded generic?

Tags: java, spring, generics, wildcard, easymock

We're looking at switching to Spring 3.0 and running into problems with the intersection of Spring 3.0, EasyMock, and Java Generics.

In one place, we're mocking a Spring 3.0 AbstractBeanFactory, specifically this method:

```
public Class<?> getType(String name) throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException { ... }
```

Under earlier versions of Spring, this returns a non-generic and all was well.  With the generic, however, we run into trouble with this:

```
expect(mockBeanFactory.getType(CLASS_NAME)).andReturn(SOME_CLASS);
```

Because `getType` returns `Class<?>`, `andReturn` requires `Class<?>` as a parameter, which simply doesn't work properly.

Is there a known workaround to this?

Comment: wouldn't this just return a warning?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've run into a problem like this before, with Mockito.  I'm not sure why it happens yet.  You can cast the expect(..) argument to the non-generic Class type, ala

```
expect((Class) mockBeanFactory.getType(CLASS_NAME)).andReturn(SOME_CLASS);
```

Then you'll just have a warning, which you can suppress if you want.  Not a very elegant solution; I'm going to spend a few more minutes looking at it.

Comment: That does the trick. Sadly, I've come to expect inelegant solutions when dealing with Java Generics.

Comment: +1 to both of you.  @AlanKrueger - I can't +1 this enough.  I spent 20 minutes *just trying to figure out how to search for this problem* :P

Comment: My guess as to why this happens is that Java can't be sure that the wildcard type that is returned from EasyMock's `expects()` will be the same type as the wildcard type that is returned from `andReturns()`. In the implementation, there is only one wildcard to for the compiler to deal with: the method's return type. The way EasyMock is set up, there needs to be two wildcards: the expected return type and the actual return type. And when there's a wildcard in each type,

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to avoid any casting and warnings is to use `expectLastCall()` instead of `expect(..)` (see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35158955/178526) for details).

So in this case:

```
mockBeanFactory.getType(CLASS_NAME);
expectLastCall().andReturn(SOME_CLASS);
```