# How to mock behavior of generic method with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, easymock

I'm using EasyMock (3.2). I want to write a test for part of my security system based on Spring Security. I want to mock the [`Authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) so that it returns empty list of authorities. Its method declaration is as follows:

```
 Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

So I write a test:

```
Authentication authentication = createMock(Authentication.class);
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.emptyList();
expect(authentication.getAuthorities()).andReturn(authorities);
```

But the compiler is complaining about the third line on `andReturn` call:

`The method andReturn(Collection<capture#1-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>) in the type IExpectationSetters<Collection<capture#1-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>> is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<capture#2-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>`

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE:

When I change the declaration of `authorities` to:

```
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.emptyList();
```

as suggested, it still does not compile, but the error is a bit different:

`The method andReturn(Collection<capture#1-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>) in the type IExpectationSetters<Collection<capture#1-of ? extends GrantedAuthority>> is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<GrantedAuthority>)`

I ensured that the `GrantedAuthority` is actually the same in both declarations - `org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority`.

Comment: Do you need the wildcard generic, or can you just go with `Collection<GrantedAuthority>`?

Comment: What is the actual return type of the getAuthorities() getter?

Comment: Using upper-bounded wildcards in the return type of methods is usually a bad idea. Try to to make your method return an unbounded generic type.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it is not method in my code that I'm trying to mock. It's from Spring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the item type from the collection declaration, you'll get a warning but the test will work.

```
@Test
public void testFoo()
    {
    // setup
    Authentication mockAuthentication = createMock(Authentication.class);
    Collection authorities = Collections.emptyList();
    expect(mockAuthentication.getAuthorities()).andReturn(authorities);

    // exercise
    EasyMock.replay(mockAuthentication);
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> retAuth = mockAuthentication.getAuthorities();

    // verify
    EasyMock.verify(mockAuthentication);
    assertEquals(authorities, retAuth);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way you can test this function using any mocking framework. I am afraid you may have to resort to type casting. The reason being generics are skin deep when it comes to wildcards - i.e. you can specify wildcards only at the top level. So, EasyMock or any mocking framework, cannot effectively create a mock object of something which has a wildcard in it.
If you look at the message:

```
 IExpectationSetters<Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>>
```

is two level deep and that is why compiler gives it up.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this specific problem is to mock the [`AbstractAuthenticationToken`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationToken.html) class instead of the  [`Authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) interface. The default implementation from spring overrides the `getPrincipals()` method and changes the returned type from `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>` to `Collection<GrantedAuthority>`. Working code:

```
AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication = createMock(AbstractAuthenticationToken.class);
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.emptyList();
expect(authentication.getAuthorities()).andReturn(authorities);
```

However, this does not solve the problem in general.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to resort to `expectLastCall()` instead:

```
authentication.getAuthorities();
expectLastCall().andReturn(authorities);
```

Let's examine both methods:

```
public static <T> IExpectationSetters<T> expect(final T value) {
    return getControlForLastCall();
}

public static <T> IExpectationSetters<T> expectLastCall() {
    return getControlForLastCall();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T> IExpectationSetters<T> getControlForLastCall() {
    // snip
    return (IExpectationSetters<T>) lastControl;
}
```

So both methods do basically the same thing but `expect(T value)` forces `IExpectationSetters` to be of the same type as `value` while `expectLastCall()` pretty much returns everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>` means a `Collection` of *some unknown class* that extends `GrantedAuthority`. So, two separate declarations of `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>` could potentially be two different classes in regards to the wildcard. That's why the compiler complains.

You may just want `Collection<GrantedAuthority>`, which means a `Collection` of `GrantedAuthority`, which of course would permit any instance of `GrantedAuthority` or any of its subclasses to be added to the collection.

Comment: `authentication.getAuthorities())` must also be declared to return `Collection<GrantedAuthority>`.